# Using insertWithOnConflict for update or insert

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, insert-update

I need to insert or update and I found the method insertWithOnConflict of the SQLiteDatabase, but I do not know how it checks if the entry already exists.

Theoretically I need a "Where" argument to check if a certain ID exists, and if so, it should replace all other columns.

This is what I have now, but I don´t think that the second argument is the unique id

```
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(AppDatabase.COLUMN_ID, entry.getId());
    args.put(AppDatabase.COLUMN_NAME, entry.getAppname());
    args.put(AppDatabase.COLUMN_URL, entry.getAppUrl());
    database.insertWithOnConflict(AppDatabase.TABLE_FILELIST, COLUMN_ID, args, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

How can I manage this behaviour?

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure you have some appropriate constraint in your table, such as `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`.
2. When inserting, add a value to this constrained column via `ContentValues`. If inserting the new row would violate some constraint, the conflicting rows are first deleted and then the new row is inserted.

In your case, `COLUMN_ID` looks like a good candidate for `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. The second arg `nullColumnHack` with value `COLUMN_ID` in your code is not necessary, you can pass it as `null`.

Comment: Thank you. I have declared my COLUMN_ID as the unique primary. If I understood you correctly, everything is fine then and the database will detect the insertion data as equal, if the primary key overlaps ,right?

Comment: Equal in the sense that the unique column is equal. You can have non-equal values in other columns. You can try it out with a plain `insert()` without the `CONFLICT_REPLACE` - you should get an exception with "column ... is not unique" message.